# Jenkins -> powershell Invoke-WebRequest with UseDefaultCredentials

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I try to execute a PowerShell script on the Jenkins slave. It looks like:

```
stage ("Get") {
    steps {
        powershell( 
            script: '''
                $srcCommonParams = @{
                    Method = 'GET'
                    Uri = $getUri
                }
                Invoke-WebRequest @srcCommonParams -UseDefaultCredentials -Verbose
```

The question is where the default credential comes from? I thought that they are the ones on which behalf my Jenkins slave windows service runs on. The problem is that my Jenkins slave runs as **user A**, but Invoke-WebRequest complains that **user B** doesn't have sufficient privileges to do a request.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get credentials from Jenkins.
You have to add 'withCredentials' and in powershell  similar to this:

```
stage ("Get") {
steps {  withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'your-credentials-id',usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']])

powershell( 
    script: '''
          $encryptedPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "%PASSWORD%" -AsPlainText -Force
          $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("%USERNAME%", $encryptedPassword)
          $srcCommonParams = @{
            Method = 'GET'
            Uri = $getUri
        }
Invoke-WebRequest @srcCommonParams -Credential $mycreds -Verbose
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it might help someone. But the question is more about where the default credentials come from rather than how to provide credentials implicitly. I mean PowerShell script gets the default credentials from somewhere (in my case user B). I'd like to know the source.. Thanks)